# setting an array of images into a table

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

So here's my issue...

I have a custom tableViewController that I'm trying to set images with an array of images. I've declared a property of my array in my header file:

```
    NSArray *imageNames;

}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *imageNames;
```

and my array in my ViewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    self.imageNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"shop_deal.png", @"Tree.png", @"Water.png", @"Sky.png", @"Cat.png", nil];
```

and here is my attempt at putting each of these images into 4 of my sections.

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        SectionInfo *array  = [self.sectionInfoArray objectAtIndex:section];
        if (!array.sectionView)
        {
           NSString *imageName = [[self imageNames] objectAtIndex:section];
           UIImage *imageIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
           [[array sectionView] setImage: imageIcon];
**Error Message for line of code above:"`incompatible pointer types sending UIImage strong to parameter of type` `NSArray`".**



        }
        return array.sectionView;
    }
```

Now i'm not sure where I should continue with this code into to put this array into the table properly. I keep getting a warning that says:"`incompatible pointer types sending UIImage strong to parameter of type` `NSArray`". Any ideas?

Comment: "I keep getting a warning that says:..." what line of code is the warning on? I don't see anything in the code you posted to cause that error.

Comment: I just made an edit. Apologies for that.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should delete this method:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

That is fetching a "header" view. I don't think you want to have a header view.

If you read the documentation for [UITableViewDataSource](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), there are two "required methods". Implement both of those, and you should be good to go.

The first method, `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` should simply be `return self.imageNames.count;`

The second method, `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` needs to create a `UITableViewCell` object, give it an image and a name and whatever else, and then return the cell. Use the `indexPath.row` to find the array index of the item in `self.imageNames.count` that should be displayed in the cell.

More details and lots of example code can be found at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451

Answer (score 0):

You should use modern Objective-C syntax:

```
imageNames = @[@"shop_deal.png", @"Tree.png", @"Water.png", @"Sky.png", @"Cat.png"];


- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSString *imageName = [self imageNames][section]; // modern Obj.-C syntax
    UIImage *imageIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName]; // make sure this is NOT nil
    UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: imageIcon]; 

    return imageView;
}
```

Make sure this code works as you want, and then start using the SectionInfo stuff. If my above code works, the problem lies in the SectionInfo stuff

Comment: Ahbi has a better answer I think, if you are not asking about headerViews but cells instead.